# How I can create donate button in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

How can I create 3 donation button in `magento 1.9.3` on cms page .

> 1st button price is 100$
>   2nd button price is 200$
>   3rd button price is 300$

and when visitor click on button automatically redirect to checkout page

Comment: I would suggest to make 3 virtual product and add on button to link of cart with that product id

Comment: i have create 3 product but please tell me what is url of button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create 3 different product with different price as per your need and add below code to generate link for button.

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add', array('product'=>$productid,'qty'=>1, 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>
```

Where `$productid` will be id of your product.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

below code for button in file

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('your-product-id') ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>
```

Comment: thanks for Answers but i have create  button with 2 code as per your code

Comment: i have create  button with 2 code as per your code my product id is 87
1st code 
<button class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('87') ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>')->getFormKey())) ?>')" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
2nd 
<a class="button" href="<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('87') ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
but both button show 404 error